# How to Run Only One Instance of Application

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, mfc

I have a application which uses socket connection to send and receive data from another application. While creating socket it uses the port 4998 .

That is where my problem lie. Once I start my application the socket starts using port 4998. So if I want to execute the application again then I get socket binding error.

So I want to limit my application instance to one. That means if the application is already running and some one tries to run the application again by clicking the exe or shortcut icon it shouldn't run the program, instead it should bring the existing application to the Top.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may used named mutex.

Code sample from the [article](http://www.bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9911/Single-instance_applications.htm):

```
WINAPI WinMain(
  HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
  try {
    // Try to open the mutex.
    HANDLE hMutex = OpenMutex(
      MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, 0, "MyApp1.0");

    if (!hMutex)
      // Mutex doesn’t exist. This is
      // the first instance so create
      // the mutex.
      hMutex = 
        CreateMutex(0, 0, "MyApp1.0");
    else
      // The mutex exists so this is the
      // the second instance so return.
      return 0;

    Application->Initialize();
    Application->CreateForm(
      __classid(TForm1), &Form1);
    Application->Run();

    // The app is closing so release
    // the mutex.
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
  }
  catch (Exception &exception) {
    Application->
      ShowException(&exception);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By calling OpenMutex() first, you have a race condition. Call CreateMutex/Ex() first. It will tell you if the mutex already exists. Call OpenMutex() only if CreateMutex() fails with an ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error.

Comment: Any tips on how to make this work on Win7+? Global\x mutexes don't see each other from different user logon sessions...

Comment: @RomanPlášil they actually do, you must have done something wrong

Comment: Wouldn't `if (!CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, L"some GUID") || GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) return 1;` be enough!?

Answer (score 14):

When your application initializes, create a mutex. If it already exists, find the existing application and bring it to the foreground. If the application has a fixed title for its main window, it is easy to find with `FindWindow`.

```
m_singleInstanceMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, L"Some unique string for your app");
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
    HWND existingApp = FindWindow(0, L"Your app's window title");
    if (existingApp) SetForegroundWindow(existingApp);
    return FALSE; // Exit the app. For MFC, return false from InitInstance.
}
```

Comment: Why not only use FindWindow(), if window class name is unique ?

Comment: @LovelyHanibal Both instances could proceed through their FindWindow checks before either has created its window.

Answer (score 10):

/* 
I have found the necessary editing to be done. Added some extra code and edits that are needed. The present one is working perfectly for me. Thank you, Kirill V. Lyadvinsky and Remy Lebeau for the help!!

*/

```
bool CheckOneInstance()
{

    HANDLE  m_hStartEvent = CreateEventW( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"Global\\CSAPP" );

    if(m_hStartEvent == NULL)
    {
    CloseHandle( m_hStartEvent ); 
        return false;
    }


    if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) {

        CloseHandle( m_hStartEvent ); 
        m_hStartEvent = NULL;
        // already exist
        // send message from here to existing copy of the application
        return false;
    }
    // the only instance, start in a usual way
    return true;
}
```

/*
The above code works even when one tries to open up second instance FROM A DIFFERENT LOGIN LEAVING THE FIRST LOGIN OPEN with ITS INSTANCE RUNNING.
*/

Comment: if m_hStartEvent is already NULL, probably best to skip CloseHandle( m_hStartEvent );

Answer (score 6):

Create named event on the start and check the result. Close application if the event is already exist.

```
BOOL CheckOneInstance()
{
    m_hStartEvent = CreateEventW( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"EVENT_NAME_HERE" );
    if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) {
        CloseHandle( m_hStartEvent ); 
        m_hStartEvent = NULL;
        // already exist
        // send message from here to existing copy of the application
        return FALSE;
    }
    // the only instance, start in a usual way
    return TRUE;
}
```

Close `m_hStartEvent` on the app exit.

Comment: If CreatEvent() fails, you can't tell if the app is already running or not, so you should exit, not continue.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in your WindowMain function by calling the FindWindow function with the class name and the title of your main window at the very beginning. If the window exists you can either show a message to the user or simply show the window and then return:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(lzClassName, lzWindowText);
if(hWnd!=NULL)
{
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}

WNDCLASSEX wcex;
/* register window class */
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;

...
```

Comment: This is a TOCTOU race condition since you're creating the window after you check for an existing one. This allows multiple executables to continue on until one of them creates the window.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you already have a way to check if your application is running? Who needs a Mutex, if the port is already taken, you know that the app is running!

Comment: Yes Now I instead of showing the error I need to bring my application by using the process ID. Any help?

Comment: Just because the port is being used, it doesn't mean that YOUR application is using it.

Comment: @OJ,Good Catch . The port might be used by som eother app

Comment: @OJ What do you intend to do differently if some other app is using the port?

Comment: Your app is only running once, so warn the user (even better, tell the user which app is using the port), give them the option of closing that app so your app can attempt to re-bind the port.

Comment: *"What do you intend to do differently if some other app is using the port?"* - Displaying a different error prompt would be a fairly obvious choice. *"[I]f the port is already taken, you know that the app is running!"* - Er, no. You know that the port is not available. And that's really all you know. Jumping to conclusions will only confuse the user when a misleading error message pops up. I'm afraid, discarding the correct solution and proposing a code-by-coincidence scheme mandates a vote. Sorry.