# When exactly is a mutex released in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, operating-system

I successfully used a mutex, created using [`CreateMutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw) with `bInitialOwner` set to `TRUE`, for ensuring that [only a single application instance runs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531179/4593433), mutiple times without any problems.

My expectation was, that this would also scale to allowing a maximum of two simultaneous running instances as well. Here is my code aiming to achieve this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <synchapi.h>

#include <codecvt>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::cout << "New instance started.\n";

    HANDLE mutex_handle = CreateMutexW(0, TRUE, L"myMutex1");
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
        std::cout << "At least one instance is already running.\nChecking if this is the second instance...\n";

        HANDLE mutex_handle2 = CreateMutexW(0, TRUE, L"myMutex2");

        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
            std::cout << "A second instance also exists already.\n";
        }
    }

    // In every case wait for 25 seconds to simulate a long running program (e.g. GUI, etc.).
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(25000));

    return 0;
}
```

After opening the program three times I got the desired output on the third instance:

```
New instance started.
At least one instance is already running.
Checking if this is the second instance...
A second instance also exists already.
```

However even after closing all but one of the opened instances (for the sake of simplicity, say all but the third instance were closed) I still get the output from above and not the expected:

```
New instance started.
```

However after closing all instances the program behaves as expected again. This leads me to believe, that the mutexes are only freed after all instances were closed, however the documentation states:

> Use the [CloseHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) function to close the handle. The system closes the handle automatically when the process terminates. The mutex object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.

I therefore expected the mutex to be freed once its owning process terminates.

**Why does this not seem to be the case and how could I use mutexes to limit my application to two instances?**

### Additional information

My suspicion was that every subsequent thread also acquired a handle by calling `CreateMutexW` and thus the mutexes are only destroyed when the last handle is closed (e.g. the last running instance of the "batch" is closed and no more instances are running).

To mitigate this I thought I could just call [`CloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) with the handle the thread obtained, whenever the `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` is encountered. The code implementing this is below, however this lead to exactly the same behaviour as described above:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <synchapi.h>

#include <codecvt>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::cout << "New instance started.\n";

    HANDLE mutex_handle = CreateMutexW(0, TRUE, L"myMutex1");
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
        if (mutex_handle != NULL)
        {
            CloseHandle(mutex_handle);
        }

        std::cout << "At least one instance is already running.\nChecking if this is the second instance...\n";

        HANDLE mutex_handle2 = CreateMutexW(0, TRUE, L"myMutex2");
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
            if (mutex_handle2 != NULL)
            {
                CloseHandle(mutex_handle2);
            }
            
            std::cout << "A second instance also exists already.\n";
        }
    }

    // In every case wait for 25 seconds to simulate a long running program (e.g. GUI, etc.).
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(25000));

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** The code above actually does behave in the way I intended. I made a mistake testing it (by running the old binary with the initial code).

Comment: `Why does this not seem to be the case` - because instance 3, like instance 2 but unlike instance 1, has both mutex handles opened, so neither of the mutexes will be released until instance 3 terminates? "[*If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is **a handle to the existing object**, and the `GetLastError` function returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexa#return-value)

Comment: Ok, but why does the same happen with the second code snippet, too?

Comment: The mutex is also not released if I close the first instance by the way…

Comment: You confuse two different things. Whether mutex exists, and whether the mutex is owned. Existence is apparently managed by windows fully. What you need to check is if you managed to acquire ownership of the mutex rather than its existance.

Comment: In the second snippet, instance 1 keeps `mutex_handle`, instance 2 keeps `mutex_handle2`, instance 3 doesn't keep any handles. So closing instances 1 and 2 is required to clear the slate.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use use `std::mutex` instead? The recommended way for locking mutexes is `std::scoped_lock`, `std::lock` or `std::lock_guard` utilizing RAII for unlocking. If third party mutexes are used, either `std::unique_ptr` should be used, or a decorator class should provide the lock/unlock interface required by the  above RAII tools. Moreover, I always prefer `std::jthread` over `std::thread`; it `join`s automatically at destruction.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Yes.  The Windows kernel mutex works across multiple processes, but `std::mutex` doesn't.

Comment: Why are you using multiple mutexes to count instances?  You should use a single semaphore instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because the program might be terminated in a way that does not allow me to decrease the semaphore count and mutexes provide the benefit that they are autoreleased by the OS (for example also when the program was terminated using taskkill).

Comment: it seems that you have an XY problem and are trying to do something you shouldn't do to begin with - so what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the mutexes in an *owned* state but you don't call `ReleaseMutex` to let other processes in. Since you are only using the mutexes to count instances and not to do any other synchronization, just creating them "unowned" would be enough - and if the mutex you try to create already exists, close it and try next, until the max number of instances have been reached.

It could look like this:

```cpp
template<std::size_t I>
class InstanceCounter {
public:
    InstanceCounter() {
        for(m_id = 0; m_id < I; ++m_id) {
            hMtx = CreateMutexW(nullptr, false,
                                (L"MUTEX" + std::to_wstring(m_id)).c_str());
            if(not hMtx)
                throw std::runtime_error("Could not create mutex");
            if(GetLastError() != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
                return;        // we found a free slot
            CloseHandle(hMtx); // don't lock this one up
        }
        // max instances reached
        throw std::runtime_error("Max instances running");
    }
    InstanceCounter(const InstanceCounter&) = delete;
    InstanceCounter& operator=(const InstanceCounter&) = delete;
    ~InstanceCounter() { CloseHandle(hMtx); }

    std::size_t my_id() const { return m_id; }

private:
    HANDLE hMtx;
    std::size_t m_id;
};
```

And you could use it like this. Here's an example where max 3 instances are allowed:

```cpp
int main() {
    try {
        InstanceCounter<3> ic;

        std::cout << ic.my_id() << '\n';

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

        std::cout << ic.my_id() << " Done\n";
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A mutex is only active or inactive. If you want a non-binary number of wait calls to pass, you can use a primitive specifically made for that, like [semaphores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsemaphorea), which can define a maximum number calls to pass (in your case, 2).

The only gotcha with this approach is that unlike mutexes, you also need to handle the application shutting down (to decrease the semaphore count, so another instance can "get in"). That, and generally speaking, if you need 2 instances at once, there's very little reason not to allow any arbitrary number as well.

Comment: I know about semaphores, but the fact that they are not automatically released is a problem for my use case. For example I can not decrease the semaphore count when the application is terminated using taskkill.

Comment: Your solution has the same issue, as you found out yourself. Semaphores remove some of the dingy DYI from your approach (like the fact that you don't synchronize the two checks in a transaction, allowing for some nasty race conditions). If you want something for automatic, you need a cross-process storage mechanism, like shared memory or some kind of database.